# Illegal start of expression error JAVA

Tags: syntax-error

So am trying to create an app to open a url. What I have so far is the following:

```
package openkaty;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class OpenKaty {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
public static void main(String[] a) {
      public OpenKaty (String baseUrl, String docID) {
            String docURL = baseUrl+docID;

            try {
                URI uri = new URI(docURL);
                Desktop desktop = null;
                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                   desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                }

                if (desktop != null)
                {
                    desktop.browse(uri);
                }
            } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ioe) {
            }   
      }
}
```

when i declare the member class openKaty i get an *illegal start of expression* error, anyone knows what to do here? This will need to be called by another class, which will pass arguments to this class to open a specific url comprised of two parts. I am an almost complete Java novice, so please be aware that I most likely have a ridiculously simple error. Sorry ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid syntax [(prior to Java 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html):

```
catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ioe){
```

You have to catch each class separately:

```
catch (IOException ioe){
  //handle the exception
} catch (URISyntaxException urise){
  //handle the other exception
}
```

Also your class is unclosed - you are missing a curly brace at the end

Also, you cannot declare a method inside another. If you remove the line with `public static void main` (so that the constructor isn't inside it) your code should compile. Since, however, you likely need a main method (in any class), close and implement the main method before the next line (with `public OpenKaty`):

```
public static void main(String[] a){
  // add your main method code here
} // was missing
public OpenKaty(String baseUrl, String docID){
```

Also note that it's *never* a good idea to discard unknown exceptions (like you do). You can always log them before discarding, at the very least.

Other than that, the syntax seems correct to me.

Comment: even changing it to what you have does not help, and that error catch does work. The problem is still on the line where 'static main void' is declared as it is shown as an illegal start of expression. This is why i am so confused, it all seems right.

Comment: @user1782255 I can't see any `static main void` in the code you posted. If the code you use contains `static main void`, replace with `static void main`. The function name (main) must come last.

Comment: @user1782255 I stand corrected. Today I learned about the Java 7 syntax

Comment: problem still eprsists, no matter the order of main, static and void.